# How do I increase 1 value over multiple rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a item tax table that records the different tax rates for different counties in our state. Each row has an ID number (1-130). Our front end software always orders the tax options by this number when we want it alphabetical. Most of our rows were added that way but I want to be able to insert rows.

Thus I need to add 1 to every entry after a certain number (e.g. 37-130 need to all increase by one). Unfortunately, this is the primary key. Is it possible to increase this value on all of them easily? Or in a loop? I'll have to do this repeatedly as we're moving about a dozen entries if possible.

```
UPDATE ItemTax
SET ID = ID + 1
WHERE ID = Last ID number
```

Comment: Please edit your question and show sample data and desired results.

Comment: You don't have the option to have your front end software order by the column you want alphabetical?   That would be the ideal solution.  Updating the Primary Key will create problems if there are foreign keys referencing it.

Comment: How about adding a new row like OrderIndex and then order all your record on it instead of the primary key ? So if you add data in this table, you will not have to reindex the primary key.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't affect the front end software at all. It is designed that most of the time you can order, but this one system has no alphabetical option. It's a poor design choice on Microsoft's end that I was hoping to solve but I may be stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Treating your question as academic, and not endorsing this as an actual solution, you can do this:

```
UPDATE ItemTax
SET ID = ID + 1
WHERE ID > 37
```

Comment: You may need to drop the primary key constraint, or SET IDENTITY_INSERT itemtax ON, run your script, then SET IDENTITY_INSERT itemtax OFF. I agree with @JPIcard though, another column with which to order would be the way to go here

Comment: OP didn't specify that ID is an IDENTITY column, but if it is then you are absolutely correct.   And as I disclaimed, I'm not saying my answer is a good idea.   But it does answer the question.   Thing about @JFPicard's answer is that if the OP has the ability to order by a new column, then he would also have the ability to simply order by the text column he wants to alphabetize.   A new column would be an unnecessary step.

Comment: Easier than I was thinking. But the big issue is the key, and it looks like there's not good solution there.

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon how you use this id, it might be better to leave original ID column unchanged. E.g.

```
alter table TaxItem add NewID int null
GO

update TaxItem set NewID = 
case
  when ID between 37 and 130 then ID + 1
  else ID
end
```

Now you don't have to update foreign key relationships, etc.

You see, as ID usually represents a surrogate key, and should never have its value changed in a good design. So your desire to change it value leads to suspicion that you do not understand your design as well as you should. -- We all start from ignorance, I have bad some very poor decisions in the past.

If this is the only change there will ever be for NewID, you don't even need a physical column, a computed column would serve well. But if this is the first mod of many a physical column is likely a better choice.

---

You also mention inserting rows. Build in some room to insert rows and change values as needed because you have room to rearrange rows by tweaking values without having to renumber entire blocks of rows just to insert a single row, e.g.

```
update TaxItem set NewID = ID * 100
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't control the reference to the ID. The product we use determines how to order the items based on ID only. So creating NewID wouldn't be able to solve our problem. Though it seems there may be no good solution.